# apex:mapMarker marker events and color

Tags: visualforce, event, google-map

I'm looking to add some of the new apex:map functionality to one of the orgs I manage.  While it's pretty fantastic how they've made it so easy, there's also some basic things I've noticed lacking.  Specifically...

1. Controlling the color of the map markers.  This is key if you want to show more than one type of thing on the map.
2. Showing a window of data about whatever's at each marker.
3. Capturing marker-related events.  For example, I'd like to capture mouseup, so users can choose a location off the map.

Has anyone approached these challenges yet?  If so, how have you solved them?

Thanks a lot,

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Please see Summer'15 Release Preview for the upcoming improvements to the Visualforce maps.

https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Summer15

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way inherently from the tag attributes for the map marker to change the color of the map markers or apply a CSS style class to them. Both this and events could be achieved using the Google Maps V3 API if you wanted more fine grained control.

And you probably saw it in the Release Notes, but the new mapInfoWindow feature allows you to make the window of data you mentioned!